# Find if an item is in a lower dimension in a Python multidimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a three dimensional  array, called grid. I now want to find whether an item is in the list of second dimensions containing the third dimension. For example, if I have this array:

```
grid = [ [ [ "0" , "1" ] , [ "2" , "1" ] ] , [ [ "3" , "0" ] ] ]
```

I want to find whether in all of the second dimensions of a first dimension (grid[0][all]) there is a specific item in a third dimension of that ([0][all][0]). I probably am not explaining this very well, but I don't know how else to say it. The all here and in the code below is meant to signify searching all of the second dimension.

```
for i in range 2:

  if "1" in grid[i][all][1]:

    #do something
```

So this code is meant to try and have me going through both the second dimensions of the array, and then, if a value is in one of those second dimensions third dimension's at a certain point, it will do something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you say `[all]`, you can use a for-loop to iterate through the elements.

For example, `([0][all][0])`

```
for y in grid[0]:
    if y[0] == "Your Value To Look For":
        print("I found the value")
```

Comment: Isn't there a faster way? I mean, I get I could do that, but the "in" function seems to do it so quickly.

Comment: Well, the fastest way to search for "all" elements is a linear search.